# Swallowing Exception within Scala Future Method Chain

Tags: scala, amazon-s3

I have a method to create a zip file on Amazon S3 that uses Rinofly's [play-s3](https://github.com/Rhinofly/play-s3) abstraction (not that it really matters--the main thing is the use of `Future`'s). The method looks something like this:

```
def createZip(key: String): Future[String] = {
    val bucket = //get S3 bucket
    val zipFileName = //name of zip file
    val futureFile = bucket get key //Returns Future[BucketFile]
    futureFile
      .map(bucketFile => newZipFile(bucketFile.name, bucketFile.content) //Create zip file from original key
      .map(newZipFile => bucket + newZipFile) //Does an S3 PUT of the zip file in the bucket and returns Unit
      .map(unit => zipFileName) //Maps the returned unit to the zip file name once the zip file has been created and properly uploaded to S3
}
```

As you can see, the method takes an S3 key and returns the name of the corresponding zip file that was created.

I discovered via the REPL that the second map method, which does the S3 put of the new zip file, throws an exception because the S3 credentials don't have permissions. No problem--I know how to fix that.

The problem is I had no idea this was the case until I ran everything line by line in the REPL. In other words, the method gives a false positive for success.

When I run the whole method in the REPL, I get this:

```
scala> val a = createZip("test.zip")
a: scala.concurrent.Future[String] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3174c2d7
scala> import scala.concurrent.Await
Await.result(a, 120.seconds)
scala> res1: String = "test.zip"
```

The result should've been an instance of `Throwable` (an `S3Exception` FWIW).

Moreover, when I apply `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks in the REPL, it's `onSuccess` that fires.

Clearly, I am doing something to swallow or hide the generation of the exception in the bucket add call.

I would love to know how to make sure all errors get exposed.

Comment: Ahh...yes, you're right. I just `flatMap`ed and got the expected result in the REPL. I'm surprised though that the compiler or my IDE didn't warn of a type safety violation. I guess I need to think through what's happening more closely. Anyway, please make your response an answer so I can hook you up with an accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bucket.add` returns `Future[Unit]` and not `Unit`. So on this line:

```
.map(unit => zipFileName)
```

You're actually mapping a `Future[Unit]` to a `String`, which is how the error is getting lost, as you're throwing out that response. This `map`:

```
.map(newZipFile => bucket + newZipFile)
```

Should become a `flatMap` to properly flatten from `Future[Future[Unit]]` to `Future[Unit]`.

The compiler isn't smart enough to infer that you don't want to map `Future[Unit] => B`, however if you were to add type annotation, it would fail to compile.

```
.map{unit: Unit => zipFileName} // Would complain the type is not Future[Unit]
```